# How to inject code into node body after x paragraph

Tags: 8, theming

Trying to figure out if there is a way to inject code after the first or second paragraph on a node.

More specifically I am trying to inject an Adsense ad.

So far I haven't been able to find a solution or module that will do this.

Can anyone help?

I am not using paragraphs module. Just looking how to inject code right after the third or fourth

tags on the body of the node.

Comment: Is this an HTML paragraph or the Drupal module Paragraphs?
 https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

Comment: Do you the adsense module?

Comment: Tried adsense module but all they do is provide a block with adsense code. I can easily do that without the need of a module. So far I can't find a module that will inject an ad somewhere into body of the node.

Comment: Well you could just use a bit of jQuery to do that, or otherwise do some text processing in PHP. What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: I don't program much if you know any examples you can point me too that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do this would be to modify the twig template that is outputting the paragraphs (on the node).

You could loop the paragraphs render array `{{ content.field_foo }}`:

```
{% for i in content.field_foo %}
  {{ content.field_foo[i] }}

  {% if i == 1 %}
    // print your output
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`1` will be your second item, as the count starts at 0. This is just some rough untested pseudocode. But the idea is to loop over and print each item in the render array one by one, and inject the code at certain counts.

**edit**: This answer is for if you are using the Paragraphs module, which at the time of this answer is not clear from your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kevin. I am not using paragraphs module. Just looking how to inject code right after the third or fourth <p> tags on the body of the node.

Comment: So I found this guide on how to inject code at the middle of the body but it is for D7.

Comment: Guide for D7 https://www.webomelette.com/block-region-middle-body-content

Comment: @Progonat are you injecting specific data or are you getting it from a field / content type / view?